# Constructing base class and inherited class from the same file

Tags: c++, file, inheritance, constructor

I have a simple set up; two classes, one inherited from the other. In the inherited class I want to read from a file and construct the object, but my problem is that because the base class must be initialised before the constructor body, ie in the initialiser list, I have to open the file twice. I want to only open the file once, read in the data I need, close the file, and initialise the inherited object.

Is there a nice way to do this? My code looks something like this at the moment and opens the file twice:

```
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class foo{
protected:
    int _a;
public:
    foo(int a) : _a(a) {}
};

class bar : public foo{
private:
    int _b;
    pair<int, int> read_bar(string file_name) { // get a and b from a file }
public:
    bar(string file_name) : foo(read_bar(file_name).first), _b(read_bar(file_name).second) {}
};
```

I want either to be able to do something like initialise from a pair, something that looks like:

```
bar(string file_name) : (foo, _b)(read_bar(file_name)) {}
```

Or initialise foo inside the function body after the file has been read. How can this be done? I have the idea that read_bar could initialise _b and and then pass an int to construct foo? But this seems illogical and would not help in a similar situation of multiple inheritance.

This is my first question so please explain if anything is wrong in terms of how I have asked the question or written code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a [delegating constructor](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor).

```
 bar(string file_name) : bar(read_bar(file_name)) {} // Delegate to the next constructor.

 bar(pair<int, int> in) : foo(in.first), _b(in.second) {}
```

**PS**

Unless you have reason to make `read_bar` a non-`static` member function, I would recommend making it a `static` member function. It seems to me that that function would not need any instance specific logic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Presumably the second constructor should be private if it is only to be called by the first? It is strange to me that this is the best way to do this by writing a whole new redundant constructor?

Comment: @BenLivingstone, Yes to the first question. As to the second question/statement, I like to think it differently. To me, the second constructor is preferable as a `public` constructor. It is a very direct and less risky constructor. The first constructor is fraught with risks. What if there is no such file? What if you don't have permissions to read the contents of the file? What if the file doesn't have the data you need? If `read_bar` is equipped to deal with those risks, I would say, make both of them `public`.

Answer (score 1):

`foo::_a` is `protected`, so `bar` can access it directly. You can construct `foo` with a default value, and the update `_a` after reading the file.

```
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class foo {
protected:
    int _a;
public:
    foo(int a) : _a(a) {}
};

class bar : public foo {
private:
    int _b;
    pair<int, int> read_bar(string filename) {
        // get a and b from a file
    }
public:
    bar(string file_name) : foo(0) {
        pair<int, int> values = read_bar(file_name);
        _a = values.first;
        _b = values second;
    }
};
```